# can I delete folder under archive in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, deriveddata

I've machbook air with **macOS Catalina and Xcode version 11.3.1**.
I need to upgrade both my iOS and Xcode. But it's showing message that
**not sufficient space in your device**.

I checked storage. There's only **10GB free space**.
I've deleted all unnecessary stuff from my laptop and
also stored some in iCloud.

But still I need more space. I was checking below folder path:-

```
Library/Developer/Xcode/
```

I've deleted folder under **`DerivedData`**

Now I just see that **Archives** - this folder has took above **30GB** space.

Can I delete folder like **2019-04-21** this pattern under Archives folder?

After deleting those folders - will I've to face problem with my Xcode project?

```
NOTE:- all 2019 archived app were test app, sent to App Store. Now those were not in use.
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You can delete archives through the Organizer. I think that's the cleanest way. Open Organizer, right click on the archive you wish to delete, and choose to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can delete all the ipa in an archive folder. This will save a lot of space on your laptop.

You can also delete the cache on your laptop.

```
Library/Caches
```